# How do I pivot results in SQL so that I can see both the count and the individual entries?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, count, pivot

I am trying to get a count from a table which has 4 columns. The 2 I have included in the pivot_data are 'ocode' and 'cname' the other 2 relate to customer details. I am trying to show how many individual 'ocode' (options) there are for each 'cname' (product) so both the product and option can appear any number of times in any number of combinations.

I currently have the following:

```
WITH pivot_data AS(
SELECT ocode,cname
FROM mi17
)
SELECT *
FROM pivot_data
PIVOT(
COUNT(ocode)
FOR cname
IN ('Dog','Cat','Horse')
);
```

This results in the following

```
Dog    Cat    Horse
 1      2      3
```

However the ocode values will be different e.g. 'OC1', 'OC2', 'OC3'
. what I would like is:

```
    Dog    Cat    Horse
OC1  1      1       1
OC2  0      1       0
OC3  0      0       2
```

Comment: Given that we don't know what data is in your original table not sure how we have a chance of guessing how  you should get that output...

Comment: My apologies it seems that I must have deleted part of my explanation before the code snippet, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Group by` and aggregate to get your result

```
SELECT ocode
,SUM(CASE WHEN cname='Dog' THEN 1 END) DOG
,SUM(CASE WHEN cname='Cat' THEN 1 END) CAT
,SUM(CASE WHEN cname='Horse' THEN 1 END) HORSE
FROM mi17
WHERE cname IN ('Dog','Cat','Horse')
GROUP BY ocode
```

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly, not sure why I thought I needed to pivot but I appreciate your help.